# Querying Latest Available Partition in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog, data-lake

I am building an ETL pipeline using primarily state machines, Athena, S3, and the Glue catalog. In general things work in the following way:

1. A table, partitioned by "version", exists in the Glue Catalog. The table represents the output destination of some ETL process.
2. A step function (managed by some other process) executes "INSERT INTO" athena queries. The step function supplies a "version" that is used as part of the "INSERT INTO" query so that new data can be appended into the table defined in (1). The table contains all "versions" - it's a historical table that grows over time.

My question is: What is a good way of exposing a view/table that allows someone (or something) to query only the latest "version" partition for a given historically partitioned table?

I've looked into other table types AWS offers, including Governed tables and Iceberg tables. Each seems to have some incompatibility with our existing or planned future architecture:

1. Governed tables do not support writes via athena insert queries. Only Glue ETL/Spark seems to be supported at the moment.
2. Iceberg tables do not support Lake Formation data filters (which we'd like to use in the future to control data access)
3. Iceberg tables also seem to have poor performance. Anecdotally, it can take several seconds to insert a very small handful of rows to a given iceberg table. I'd worry about future performance when we want to insert a million rows.

Comment: Have you tried running select * from source-table where partition_column=(SELECT partition_column FROM "tablename$partitions" order by partition_column desc limit 1); to get latest partition info which with out scanning all partitions in source table?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that any partition I query against in the table is fully written?  In other others, is it possible to read from a partition that is currently in the process of writing?  Specifically, if I have an Athena INSERT query running does the partition only become available for a SELECT query after the INSERT finishes?

Comment: In y experience unless the partition fully written it will not have entry in tablename$partitions.